# MySQL combining 2 selects

Tags: mysql

---

### --- EDITED for clarification ---

```
TABLE tb1
id       somevalue
1        999
2        999
3        999
4        998

TABLE tb2
tb1_id      other_irrelevant_fields
3           ...
3           ...
3           ...
```

I want to get the fields of tb1 where somevalue = 999, and COUNT(*) of tb2 where tb1_id = tb1.id, in one query.

Basically joining these 2 queries into 1:

```
 1. SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE somevalue = 999
 foreach row selected:
     2. SELECT COUNT(*) from tb2 WHERE tb1_id = <id of tb1>
```

---

```
RESULT
id    somevalue    COUNT(*)
1        999       0
2        999       0
3        999       3
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. What's the link between table1 and table2 ?

Comment: s2.table1_id references table1.id

Comment: what you exactly want ?

Comment: Provide some sample data for both tables and you do not need multiple select if there is a common key you can use join

Comment: edited with example for clarification

Comment: add data to your `tb2.other_irrelevant_fields` it still not clear what do you count?

Comment: Foreach row selected in tb1, count the number of rows in tb2 where tb2.tb1_id = tb1.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a LEFT-JOIN if you want all records in table 1 regardless of a match in table 2...  And the count should be based on finding a record in the 2nd table.

```
select 
      tb1.id,
      tb1.somevalue,
      count( tb2.tb1_id ) as Tbl2Records
   from
      tb1
         LEFT JOIN tb2
            on tb1.id = tb2.tb1_id
   where
      tb1.somevalue = 999
   group by
      tb1.id,
      tb1.somevalue
```

Comment: @tumber033, so did this work for you???  Also check out at the Help > Tour for site etiquette.  Marking questions as answered helps others know what worked vs still open item.  Also, up-arrow on questions (on this and others as you search) show you found the answer useful, even if something may have been informative or near what you may have been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tb1.*, count(tb2.*) 
FROM tb1
LEFT JOIN tb2
ON tb1.id=tb2.tb1_id
WHERE tb1.somevalue = 999
GROUP BY tb1.id
```

Comment: Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers. While the person asking this question may understand your answer, explaining how you arrived at it could help countless others.